# Does abort run in ring 0?

Tags: c++, c, x86

These days i found a blog the mentioned abort function in C.

The following is the source code of abort function:
http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/0_9_14/libc/stdlib/abort.c

I found that it use the `hlt` instruction (My PC is x86).

But seems that `hlt` must run in ring 0.
(refer to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT)

It seems that the abort is running in the user space. So the usage of the `hlt` instruction in abort seems illegal.

BTW, I try to run `hlt` in linux and windows. But i encounter an error.

In linux:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define HLT_INST asm("hlt")

int main(){
  cout<<"whill run halt"<<endl;

  HLT_INST; //result in SIGSEGV error
  return 0;
}
```

In Windows:

```
cout<<"will run hlg"<<endl;
/*Unhandled exception at 0x0040101d in test_learn.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
*/
__asm{
    hlt;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `abort` function only uses the `hlt` instruction after sending `SIGABRT` fails. If you read the source code, the function first tries to:

```
raise(SIGABRT);
```

And then calls the invalid instruction :

```
/* Still here?  Try to suicide with an illegal instruction */
if (been_there_done_that == 2) {
    been_there_done_that++;
    ABORT_INSTRUCTION;
}
```

So you are right, `hlt` requires ring 0 privileges. That's precisely what makes it an invalid instruction. Executing it will call an invalid-instruction handler, which is in your case (I suppose) SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the [SIGABRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT) POSIX signal

for instance, if you hit a `abort()` call while debugging with GDB, you'll see:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003c47e352d5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000003c47e352d5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003c47e36beb in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400721 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde18) at test.c:27
```

As @kbok mentionned, the disassembly of the `abort` function include the `hlt` instruction:

```
(gdb)  disassemble abort
Dump of assembler code for function abort:
...
0x0000003c47e36b08 <+152>:  hlt
...
```

(but it does `SEGFAULT indeed`)

```
(gdb) break *0x0000003c47e36b08
Breakpoint 2 at 0x3c47e36b08
(gdb) jump *0x0000003c47e36b08
Breakpoint 2, 0x0000003c47e36b08 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function abort,which has no line number information.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003c47e36b08 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```